# Lexicographically sort file by line, reading right-to-left

Tags: sorting, unix, command-line

I'm looking for a command-line (ideally) solution that lets me sort the lines in a file by comparing each line from right to left.

For example...

Input:

```
aabc
caab
bcaa
abca
```

Output:

```
bcaa
abca
caab
aabc
```

I'll select the answer which I think will be the easiest to remember in a year when I've forgotten I posted this question, but I'll also upvote clever/short answers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest to remember would be

```
reverse < input | sort | reverse
```

You will have to write a [`reverse`](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/05/different-ways-to-reverse-string-in.html) command though. Under Linux, there's `rev`.